# How to List all Mailers in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say you have some mailers, but you want a dynamic list of them, how would you go about doing this?

The list is of all the mailer classes within a Rails application that inherit from `ActionMailer::Base`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
> ActionMailer::Base.descendants
=> [Devise::Mailer]
> Dir['app/mailers/*.rb'].each {|f| require File.basename(f, '.rb')}
> ActionMailer::Base.descendants
=> [Devise::Mailer, InternalMailer, MailingListMailer, MessageMailer, UserMailer]
```

There may well be better ways.  Note that if your mailers are somewhere else (or in nested directories) you'd need to modify the Dir glob above.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like if you do `Dir['app/mailers/**/*.rb']` you get a lovely `LoadError: cannot load such file` error. This is enough to test if its a directory and make your answer recursive!